# Where do I get started on drawing nice interactive shapes?

Tags: javascript, graphics, 2d, shapes

I'm trying to draw nice shapes in javascript, but all these libraries are really confusing. Not in terms of use, but in terms of how they operate in the background. I'm trying to understand, when I declare a shape on the JS side, is that converted to an HTML div, and styled with CSS? (excluding WebGL here) how are shapes rendered behind the scenes?

Comment: It might be SVG. You can check by looking at the output in the developer tools.

Comment: It could use SVG, or the canvas 2D context, either directly or through one of the many libraries that use those technologies. Inspect the html in the developer tools to find the technology being used and then look at the loaded js libraries to identify any graphics libraries being used.

Comment: I've learned that there's the DOM (raw HTML+CSS) and/or SVG level, and there's pixel rendering with Canvas and WebGL. D3.js uses SVG under the hood. I guess I'll go with that for now..